# Скрипт в Google Spreadsheets не запускается по тригерам

Tags: события, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

У меня полностью рабочий скрипт, который берет кое где данные и вставляет в таблицу, если тупо нажать Run то все нормально заполняется.
Но мне нужно, чтоб запустилось при изменении ячейки.
В общем, я пробовал и onEdit(event) и onOpen(event), ничего не происходит.
Я даже так пробовал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может как то прикрепить скрипт надо к таблице?

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, пример кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишите функцию [onEdit(event)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#Simple) в самом скрипте. Он будет вызван триггером, как указано на вашем скриншоте.